# Django 2.2 и поле модели DateField

Tags: django

**Задача:** При создании поста в блоге пользователь не должен заполнять поля с датой начала и датой окончания, они должны заполняться текущей датой автоматически.

**Вопрос:** Как предать дату в поле DateField?
Я перепробовал многие варианты но ничего не помогает, пост просто не сохраняется...

Может есть более простой вариант работы с полями типа DateField? Если использовать auto_now_add=True Django ругается т.к. такая конструкция уже используется в этой модели.

---

**models.py**

```
beginning_date = models.DateField('Начало события', default=date.today, blank=True)
ending_date = models.DateField('Окончание события', default=date.today, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    new_post_form = NewPostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if new_post_form.is_valid():
        post = new_post_form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.beginning_date = date.today
        post.ending_date = date.today
        post.is_blog_post = True
        post.save()
```

**Полный models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField('Идентификатор', max_length=255, db_index=True, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField('Пост')
    image = models.ImageField('Обложка', default='post_image.png', upload_to='posts_images', null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(VertexUser, related_name='post_author', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор')
    views = models.ManyToManyField(VertexUser, related_name='post_views', verbose_name='Просмотры', blank=True)
    like = models.ManyToManyField(VertexUser, related_name='users_post_like', verbose_name='Лайки', blank=True)
    dislike = models.ManyToManyField(VertexUser, related_name='users_post_dislike', verbose_name='Дизлайки', blank=True)
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации', auto_now_add=True)
    editing_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата редактирования', auto_now=True)
    is_event = models.BooleanField('Событие', default=False)
    beginning_date = models.DateField('Начало события', auto_now_add=True)
    ending_date = models.DateField('Окончание события', auto_now_add=True)
    is_news = models.BooleanField('Новость', default=False)
    is_blog_post = models.BooleanField('Пост', default=False)
    is_edit = models.BooleanField('Отредктированно', default=False)
    on_main = models.BooleanField('На главную', default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField('Опубликованно', default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} | Автор: {self.author} | Опубликованно {self.active}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail_page', args=[str(self.slug)])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пост'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Посты'
```

Comment: `auto_now_add=True` (без параметров `default` и `blank`) должен работать для Вас. Приведите, пожалуйста, ошибку, которая возникает при этом подходе.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Трэйс: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'beginning_date' cannot be specified for Post model form as it is a non-editable field - Возникает на этапе makemigrations...

Comment: @nomnoms12 Так же выложил полный models.py

Comment: Вы случайно не добавили это поле в форму модели? Если так, то попробуйте удалить его из формы (так как это поле неизменяемое).

Comment: Да, в форме есть. Но мне нужно сделать так что бы обычный пользователь даже не видел эти поля, а админ ручками устанавливал дату начала и дату окончания...

Comment: Как именно админ должен устанавливать значения? Как Вы планируете разделять форму для админа и обычного пользователя? Конкретно сейчас Ваша ошибка в том, что поле с `auto_now_add=True` неизменяемое и его нельзя указывать как изменяемое поле формы (следовательно нужно удалить). Если Вам требуется, чтобы поле было изменяемым, используйте `default=datetime.datetime.now` (или иное, без параметра `auto_now_add`). Тогда, чтобы пользователь не смог его изменить и не видел в принципе, исключите это поле из формы для пользователя.

Comment: Система такая. Админ и пользователь через одну и ту же форму на сайте ( не в админке)создают пост. В шаблоне стоит условие если у пользователя is_admin == True  то поля показаны, в противном случае в форме показаны все поля кроме даты начала и даты окончания. Ну дальше во views.py я разбираю реквес.ПОСТ и если админ изменил даты, то они записываются, если не изменял то в них записывается текущая дата.

Comment: Выше я опечатался с параметром `default` (не заметил, что Вам нужна только дата). В общем попробуйте `default=datetime.date.today` (`import datetime`. **Именно так!**). Я думаю, что ошибка у Вас в импортировании. Как именно Вы подгружаете `datetime`? Нужно импортировать именно базовый модуль, это важно!

Comment: И не забудьте проверить наличие прав администратора при изменении этих полей. Иначе их можно будет изменять, несмотря на то, что они скрыты на `frontend`'е.

Comment: Я пробовал так: from datetime import date в поле DateField (default = date.today) во views.py точно также импортировал и использовал такую конструкцию: post.beginning_date = date.today. Дебажил через print(post.beginning_date) туда прилетает 2019-12-08, но не сохраняется (((  так же пробовал менять на date.today() и timezone.now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось проблема заключается в том что через отправку формы поле типа DateField не может быть пустым и формат даты должен быть YYYY-DD-MM (год-день-месяц). Соответственно реализовать необходимый мне функционал получилось так:

**views.py**

```
import time

***
post.beginning_date = time.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")
```

Таким образом разбирая request.POST у меня получилось передать в post.beginning_date текущую дату и успешно записать post.

*ВАЖНО!*
для time.strftime критичен регистр форматирования.